# Can't serve two static websites with Nginx

Tags: nginx, nginx-config, nginx-location

I have two React build folders and I want to access them like this :

```
https://example.com/ -> /var/www/web_client/
https://example.com/videochat/ -> /var/www/videochat/
```

Here is my nginx configuration file :

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    server_name example.com;

    location / {
        root /var/www/web_client;
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }

    location /videochat/ {
        root /var/www/videochat;
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on;
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;
}
```

The location block `/` works perfectly but `/videochat/` redirects me to the 404 page of `/var/www/web_client` and not the index.html of `/var/www/videochat`.

How can I fix this error and get nginx to serve both static websites on the same server ?

I tried to reverse the two like this to make sure the error is coming from nginx:

```
    location / {
        root /var/www/videochat;
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }

    location /web_client/ {
        root /var/www/web_client;
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }
```

Now it's the other way around, the location block `/` redirects me to the index.html of `/var/www/videochat` as expected but `/web_client/` redirects me to `/var/www/videochat` and not the index.html of `/var/www/web_client`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try having /videochat location block first and then then the / location block.
Because location /, will be the block that gets used for both / as well /videochat.
Only if we specify '=' in the location match, it will be a exact match, if not requested URI will be matched against the beginning of the mentioned URI in the location block.
For many location blocks it will be better to use regex.
You can refer to article like this for more info:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/nginx-location-directive

Comment: Thank you for your help, unfortunately I tried and it didn't solve my problem.